# Paginate Grouped Entries

Tags: entries, pagination, group

I am trying to paginate grouped entries as follows...

```
{% set searchParam = craft.request.getParam('q') %}

{% set groups = craft.entries({
    search: searchParam
})|group('section') %}

{% for entries in groups %}
    {% paginate entries.limit(10) as pageEntries %}

    {% endpaginate %}
{% endfor %}
```

However it is throwing this error on the paginate line: `Array to string conversion`

How else can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: Where do you want to break pages? After x entries or after x groups? If entries, a group from page 1 most likely gets continued on page 2 and you need additional group headings etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is occurring at `entries.limit(10)`, because at that point `entries` is already an array of fetched entries, rather than an ElementCriteriaModel. (The entries will get fetched as soon as the ElementCriteriaModel is passed to your `|group` filter.)

The only way to grab just 10 entries per section (per page) will be to loop through each of your sections, and create a new ElementCriteriaModel for each one.

```
{% set sections = {
    'news': 'News',
    'events': 'Events',
    // ...
} %}

{% for section, sectionName in sections %}

    {% set entries = craft.entries.section(section).limit(10) %}
    {% paginate entries as pageInfo, pageEntries %}

    {% if pageEntries|length %}
        <h3>{{ sectionName }}</h3>

        {% for entry in pageEntries %}
            <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Note that Craft does not support multiple independently paginated lists of entries on a single webpage. So if you use the built-in `{% paginate %}` tag like this, when it takes you to page 2, all of the sections’ `{% paginate %}` tags will start showing page 2 content. And you’ll need to keep track of which section actually has the most pages, before building out your pagination nav.

```
// ...

{% set primaryPageInfo = null %}

{% for section, sectionName in sections %}

    {% set entries = craft.entries.section(section).limit(10) %}
    {% paginate entries as pageInfo, pageEntries %}

    // ...

    {# Does this section have the most entries (so far)? #}
    {% if not primaryPageInfo or pageInfo.totalPages > primaryPageInfo.totalPages %}
        {% set primaryPageInfo = pageInfo %}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

{# Build out the pagination nav using the biggest section's pageInfo #}
<a href="{{ primaryPageInfo.firstUrl }}">First Page</a>
{% if primaryPageInfo.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ primaryPageInfo.prevUrl }}">Previous Page</a>{% endif %}
{% if primaryPageInfo.nextUrl %}<a href="{{ primaryPageInfo.nextUrl }}">Next Page</a>{% endif %}
<a href="{{ primaryPageInfo.lastUrl }}">Last Page</a>
```